# "E_INVALID_NEW_RECORD",

Tags: sails.js

{
"code": "E_INVALID_NEW_RECORD",
"details": "Missing value for required attribute `EMP_ID`. Expected a number, but instead, got: undefined",
"message": "The server could not fulfill this request (`POST /employee/create`) due to a problem with the parameters that were sent. See the `details` for more info. **The following additional tip will not be shown in production**: Tip: Check your client-side code to make sure that the request data it sends matches the expectations of the corresponding attribues in your model. Also check that your client-side code sends data for every required attribute."
}

Comment: Pls help some body to correct this error in the program file

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Kindly add more details to your question.

Comment: this is my model file

Comment: when i am trying to insert the data using post method on the browser extension its giving this error , can help me out how to solve this problem

Comment: Edit your question and add the reason in the question, so that everyone can see it.